# Module "oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends" does not define a "EmailBackend" attribute/class

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am trying to start a project based on django-oscar from scratch and stacking with problem

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
Module "oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends" does not define a "EmailBackend" attribute/class
```

My `settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: It is `oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.Emailbackend`.

Comment: thanks a lot! strange that the error here https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/blob/master/sites/demo/settings.py

Comment: For some reason, I thought I had installed version 0.8. Now I realize my stupid machine did version 0.7!! Thanks for the "b" tip!

Answer (score 4):

The error happens because the "b" in "EmailBackend" should not be a capital.

**From Oscar Documentation (Wrong):**

'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.Email**B**ackend',

**SHOULD BE:**

'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.Email**b**ackend',

---

It was mentioned above, but not very clearly. Hope this helps others who stumble upon this :)